# Infer recursive array type

Tags: typescript

I can try to create type for nested array. Type `NestedArray` works good if we specify the type explicitly:

```
type NestedArray<T> = T | NestedArray<T>[];

const arr01: NestedArray<string | number> = ['foo', ['bar', 55]];
const arr02: NestedArray<string> = ['foo', ['bar', 55]];
//                                                 ^^
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'NestedArray<string>'
```

But for inference type I got error for array `[string, [number]]` and I couldn't understand why (how TS works in this case):

```
function f<T>(arr: NestedArray<T>): NestedArray<T> {
    return arr;
}

// Works as excepted

const arr1 = f(['foo', 5]); // NestedArray<string | number>
const arr2 = f(['foo', [5, 'bar']]); // NestedArray<string | number>
const arr3 = f(['foo', 5, ['bar']]); // NestedArray<string | number>

// But for next array I got error

// const arr4 = f(['foo', [5]]); // NestedArray<number>
//                 ^^^^^
//                 Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'NestedArray<number>'.
```

I found work solution in source of `Array.prototype.flat`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2019.array.d.ts#L21 but I want to understand how TS compiler works for `NestedArray` (maybe step-by-step) and why I got errors:

```
type FlatArray<Arr, Depth extends number> = {
    "done": Arr,
    "recur": Arr extends ReadonlyArray<infer InnerArr>
        ? FlatArray<InnerArr, [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20][Depth]>
        : Arr
}[Depth extends -1 ? "done" : "recur"];
```

TypeScript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMCCAndBDEAeAKgHxQC8U+UAPrAkmpjgYQNoC6A3AFCcBmArgDsAxsACWAewFQeTABRZMALhqIUGbHiIBKZXFX0NTKAG9OUc1HQRgfdFIXouAX25DJiKA4CMpabOYA5Dzi4gEANFAArKxa7FAA9PEqdOqMiOiiAgDmVFACfAC2AEYQ6IScbgIeDgBMvjz+QSHhUMyREQFFCgGsMXGJyWoMeOmZOdT5xaXlldWYAMz1jcGhEe2tnd29sQlJeinDuKPZuZMlZdwDs8CemAAsS4ErLW3b-Xu0Q4Zn05wDFgDAQCAHqg0F-JJAqEWfDgaABY5ZAJQUTwPLiG5YeDwURZARYIoAG2gwHEUFAkCgAX2X0YPzKAQAdJwgA